# Applying logic to button Make Copy - Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I just started with Netsuite and Suitescript 2.1. I am wondering if I can apply any logic to the "Make Copy" button via suitescript.
The make copy button is on the opportunity > sublist Item > Line item.
Examples of what I want to do:

- Reset certain fields of the copied line
- Fill in certain fields of the copied line (with a certain logic
  behind it)

[image]

Comment: Copying is a user event.  Write a User Event Script and in your beforeLoad function, call the code on scriptContext.type = scriptContext.UserEventType.COPY.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatly this will be done server side, however I could use beforeSubmit in my situation. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution. I use the validateLine function. When making a copy of a lineitem in Netsuite the lineitem field: "line" has an empty string value until the line is created by clicking the "Add" button or clicking outside of the copied lineitem. I will check if that field is empty, if yes it means the line is a copy. Afterwards I can also set a custom field isCopy = true.

```
       const lineIsCopied = () => {
            let lineNumber = opportunity.getCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'line'
            });

            if (lineNumber) {
                //linenumber is existing this means line is not a copy
                return false;
            } else {
                //linenumber is empty this mean line is a copy
                return true;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the 'validateInsert' within a Client Script.
Make sure your function return 'true' for a valid insert, otherwise any insert for any sublist won't succeed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The validateInsert is not getting triggered when copying the line.